# how to open a timeline window

Tags: interface

There is supposed to be a timeline, but when I made my first keyframe, the keyframe timeline didn't appear.

How can I make timeline appear?

[image: screenshot of lack of timeline]

Comment: to learn how to re-arrange blender's interface read: http://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/basics/interface/window_system/arranging_frames.html

Answer (score 11):

Pull upward on the hatched corner to create a new area: [image: pulling up from corner]

Then, click on the editor type selector and choose *Timeline*:[image]

You now have a timeline in the new area.

Comment: The hatched corner is sometimes not in the bottom left, but in the top right corner of the "main content" part of the screen. So if you are like me looking for it on the bottom left, look for it on the top right !

Answer (score 0):

If you by accident went into full screen mode (with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>) you can hit that again to bring it back to normal interface. I couldn't find those three bars in the corner to bring up the timeline but once I exited full screen mode, it showed up (2.79 Version).