# The bar at the very bottom of the screen has gone away?

Tags: interface, video-sequence-editor

The bar at the very bottom of the screen went away while I was trying to make an intro, its the one with all the frames and options of view, marker, frame, playback, start, end, and the play button. Please help me, how do I get it back!?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/36239/599

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Click on a transparent '***+***' button in the down right part of a screen.
[image]

Maybe you accidentaly *collapsed menus*. Hover your cursor over the bottom bar, then press RMB and uncheck the ***Collapse Menus*** box.
[image]

If you want to have many different windows (editors) opened at once you can add them by:

- clicking on the corner of the window and dragging it in any diection:
  [image]
- using a ***Split Area*** option (press the RMB while hovering cursor over the border of the window)
  [image]

With multiple windows opened you can change the editor type for each of them by clicking on *area type* button as I've shown above. In your case change the editor type for one of them to ***Timeline***.
[image]

Comment: I have that bar but in the video i was watching there was another bar below that one with the play button i dont have that

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot to show us what your windows layout look like?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yMZ5g_nWqvs&list=WL

Comment: There is the video i was watching skip to about 20 mins when he is adding in the music...at the very bottom there is the bar in which you helped with, but then there is another below that with the play button i dont have that one

Comment: @GreenLegend88 I've updated an answer. Hope this is the solution you're looking for :).

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Maybe you accidentally collapsed the area that we call the 'Header' and you'll see a small <kbd>+</kbd> symbol attached to the bottom of the view area.

Answer (score 2):

The `+` is shown in the bottom right corner of an *Area*, so if you can't find it at first in the *Main Region*, it may just be that you have the *Properties Region* enabled (hotkey: <kbd>N</kbd>) which means it'll be in that lower right corner, it just might be harder to spot because of any property *Panels*:

[image: Imgur]

- https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/interface/window_system/areas.html
- https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/interface/window_system/regions.html
  states

  > The *Header* can be hidden with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>

  but I find (2.78 Windows) this key combination toggles it (i.e. it also shows it when it's hidden).