# How to Reopen the 3D Viewport along side the UV Edit Window

Tags: interface, 3d-view, uv-image-editor

I opened the UV edit window and made a uv map. Now I want to open up a second window with my model in the 3D viewport. I want to synchronize the mesh and the uv map. But I can't figure out how to open the 3D viewport.

Thank you for your help,

Sabia

Comment: To learn the basics of customizing the user interface please read the following links on the blender manual: https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/window_system/introduction.html and  https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/window_system/areas.html

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36239/how-to-open-a-timeline-window and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1223/how-to-close-open-a-view-panel

Answer (score 2):

I have created a hotkey for performing this most frequently needed operation with areas.

1. <kbd>RMB</kbd> click on the edge between two areas
2. Choose `Split Area`
3. Right Click on it again.
4. Choose `Add Shortcut`
5. Press the hotkey you would want to use for splitting areas (I used <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>)
6. Then press the hotkey to initiate the split.
7. Pressing <kbd>MMB</kbd> button can change the direction of split.
8. Click the mouse when satisfied with the proportions of split.

[image: Creating a hotkey for splitting]

**References**

[Arranging Areas in Blender](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/window_system/areas.html#arranging)

Answer (score 1):

Adding a new resizeable area is done by grabbing the diagonal lines ("[little ridged thumb grips](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/window_system/areas.html)") that are present at the corners of all areas and moving them to the desired direction, to obtain an "up-down" or a "left-right" split.

Once created, each area can be assigned to a different type of editor.

An area can be removed by "coalescing" a neighboring area onto it. This is done by grabbing the same handle and, while holding the mouse button, moving the pointer to the center of the area that you need to remove.

Here's an animation of what you are trying to achieve

[image: split, resize and join blender editor areas]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to simply shut down with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>. When I came back in, I was able to cleanly do what I wanted rather than trying to exit wherever I had gotten to! So I recommend that to anyone. Save if you need to, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and come back in! Do not try to find your way out of the *labyrinthine* paths of Blender. :-D

I read some of the manual's interface info as suggested. Thank you for those suggestions.